# Selecting Some Members from a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Let's assume:

```
R = [1     2     3; ...
     4     5     6; ...
     7     8     9; ...
     ];
```

How I can pick* only three members from it: `R(1,1)` , `R(1,3)` and `R(3,3)`

It means I am looking for

```
 B =
     1
     7 
     9
```

Please bear in mind that `B = [R(1,1), R(1,3), R(3,3)]` or "loop" solution is not the answer as I need to do it for a large data. So, preferably using indexing solution. Thanks

- The rule (condition) for picking the member is:
  `R(i,j)` that `i = [ 1, 3, 3]` and `j = [1 , 1 , 3]`;

Comment: `B = [R(1,1), R(1,3), R(3,3)]`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I need to do this procedure for a huge data. So, I will edit the question to emphasize that I am not looking for that manual recalling.

Comment: @Iman be sure to mention the rule by which you want to pick your numbers... Are these some numbers at random? Or just the non-top-right corners?

Comment: OK, I will edit the question to mention the rule.

Comment: @excaza Let me check the question. Thanks

Comment: @excaza Thanks for your help. So, I don't know should I mention the answer here or just remove my question. Any thoughts? 
Using linear indexing directly without calling SUB2IND is the fastest solution:
rows = [1 3 3];
columns = [1 1 3];
output = R( size(R,1)*(columns -1) + rows )

Comment: @excaza OK. I will remove it. Thanks though for your response and time <3

Comment: @excaza I am about to delete my question. But, the site says deleting my question will give me some negative points. Is that right?

Comment: @Iman you will lose the 2 points you gained from accepting the answer.

Comment: Noooo no no! Don't delete questions with upvoted answers! That's bad! While the question might be redundant, we have to appreciate the work made by others in answering your post. I know it's not your fault @Iman and thanks for being compliant:) But answered questions are not safe to delete.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok, I got confused with whethe I delete it or not! So, I will leave it like that for a while. I have to go now. But, rethink over it later. Cheers

Comment: @Iman just leave it around. Duplicates are not necessarily a bad thing, only bad duplicates are. [Here's a meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/5067311) which notes that self-deleting after an answer is very bad, and considered a hostile gesture. Even if everybody involved (mainly Suever and you) agrees, it would count against you a lot. If there are no answers yet, then self-deleting is OK:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `ismember` to find all 1, 7, or 9's

```
B = A(ismember(A, [1 7 9]));
```

otherwise if you want specific locations and you have the rows and columns, just use `sub2ind` to create a linear index

```
rows = [1 3 3];
columns = [1 1 3];

B = A(sub2ind(size(A), rows, columns));
```

As the dupe answer points out you can definitely do the following but you sacrifice readability.

```
B = A(size(A, 1) * (columns - 1) + rows);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying. But, firstly ismember is relatively slow for large data. Because, it will search all of members for find the result. 
Secondly, I am looking for a solution to select members with respect to their index.

Comment: @Iman Please read the entire answer...

Comment: @Iman Also if what you actually need to do was the first thing, then `ismember` is going to be as fast as you can get. It will certainly be faster than using `find` or any similar function

Comment: Oh, I just see the second part. Let me run it in my code. I'll pick it as a correct answer if it works quickly. Thanks

Comment: Thank for your time. I found a solution that is probably the fastest method:
rows = [1 3 3]; columns = [1 1 3]; output = R( size(R,1)*(columns -1) + rows )

Answer (score 0):

```
R = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; % Your matrix
B = R([1,3,9])             % indices
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your answer is working perfectly accurate and fast. But, I was looking for a solution with indexing. Please read my above comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. The `R(:)` is completely unnecessary and the OP doesn't know the linear indices.

Comment: `original col*original row` is not how you get linear indices from subscripts.

Comment: Thanks Suever! I have updated the answer.

Comment: @OsJoe He still doesn't know the values `[1 3 9]`...